# Ending EOF not detected

Tags: bash, eof, psql

I have the following function;

```
function getdetails {
    if ! "${PSQL_PATH}" -d "$DB" -U "$DB_USER" -h localhost -p "$DB_PORT" -t -c  | while read -a Record ; do
        taskid="${Record[0]}"
        clientname="${Record[1]}"
        backup_pass="${Record[2]}"
        backup_dir="${Record[3]}"
      done; then
            echo "Could not fech next task metadata from database"
            exit 1
      fi <<EOF
        WITH firsttask AS (SELECT taskid from tasks 
                            WHERE status = 'PENDING'
                            ORDER BY date_started ASC
                            LIMIT 1)
        SELECT taskid, username, storage_password AS backup_password, location AS backup_dir 
        FROM firsttask 
        INNER JOIN users USING (userid)
        INNER JOIN storage USING (userid)
        WHERE (username = '$1');
EOF 
}
```

For some reason, bash does not detect the last `EOF` and reports:

`` ./processor.sh: line 138: warning: here-document at line 41 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
./processor.sh: line 139: syntax error: unexpected end of file ``

Any ideas why the `EOF` is not picked up? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It fails because the closing `EOF` word has trailing whitespace. It must be on a line by itself, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

An exception is when using the `<<-` syntax, in which case the closing word may be preceded by one or more TABs (but never spaces).

Comment: Can't believe I missed this. Thank you!

Comment: thank god, I found this